# I got error in java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i have error in edit cart item in my app.the error is : `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"`.i thing error line  `interget.parseInt("" + v.getTag());`

my code :

```
case R.id.iv_edit_cart_item:
                    FragmentManager fm=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    Fragment fragment = new ProductDetailActivity();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    int updatePos = Integer.parseInt("" + v.getTag());
                    bundle.putString("key","update");
                    bundle.putString("product_id", mArrListMyCart.get(updatePos).getmStrProductId());
                    bundle.putString("item_id", mArrListMyCart.get(updatePos).getmStrItemId());

                    getUpdateCartItems();
                    //showAlert("Product id-->" + mArrListMyCart.get(Integer.parseInt(""+v.getTag())).getmStrProductId(), -1);
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack("").commit();
                    break;
```

How to solve this?

Comment: `int updatePos = v.getTag() != null ? Integer.parseInt("" + v.getTag()) : 0;`

Comment: can you explain please @Azola & how to add in above coding..

Comment: This is a check whether the value of v.getTag() is null or empty.

Comment: The code cheks if `v.getTag()` is not `null`, if it is not null then you can convert the `string` to a `int`, otherwise default to `0`

Comment: @Azola nice explanation

Comment: i changed my code.it works.thanks lot.@Azola.i need another help.do you?

Comment: @Thiru what is the problem?

Comment: i'm the new one in android.can you teach me in android.please.....@Azola

Comment: No expert in Android either, because you are working on app already I believe you can do some learning on your own like I did. Good luck!

Comment: @Thiru my answer did not resolve your issue?

Comment: ok.i understand.but if i have doubt can i ask you? @Azola

Comment: your answer already told Azola.that fix my issue.@ Sagar Gangawane

Comment: i have another error. using                                                                             int updatePos = v.getTag() != null ? Integer.parseInt("" + v.getTag()) : 0;    this line  i get another line error...that line is,                                              if (mArrListProductDetail.get(position).getmStrIsRequired().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {                                                                                                                                         @Azola

Answer (score 2):

The `java.lang.NumberFormatException` comes when you try to parse a non-numeric `String` to any Number like `Integer` or `Double`.

For example, if you try to convert `"null"` to an `integer` then you will get `NumberFormatException`.

The error `"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException:` For input string: "null" is specifically saying that the String you receive for parsing is not numeric.

Please ensure `v.getTag()` is not null before parsing.

```
String input = v.getTag();

If( null != input ) 
{
  int updatePos = Integer.parseInt("" + input);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

check XML and ensure that all of your Views have this attribute: **android:tag="someTag"**

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="someTag"/>
```